# Android checkBox onClick app doesn't work, stops unexpectedly?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator, ddms

So,

I am building a basic app which has 2 activivities. Now, the first one works well, the second one does not. It does not show any errors while I edit the codes, but when I run the app and when I am in the second acitivity it gives me an annoying error. Saying "Stops unexpectedly...." You know. I tried debugging but failed. In the second activity called Troll.java I should be able to check a checkbox and when I do that a text is supposed to change to something else. It says stops unexpe.....

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<include
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 layout="@layout/resuable_pizza_layout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
    android:text="@string/display"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lol"
    android:onClick="onlol"
    android:contentDescription="@string/lol2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/display"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lol" />
```

troll.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF69B4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onChecked1"
        android:text="@string/ch1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onChecked2"
        android:text="@string/ch2"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.26" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/trollFace"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

mainActitvity.java :

```
package com.example.pizza2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CheckBox pepp, cheese;
TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pepp = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
    cheese = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

}

public void onShow(View view){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    if (pepp.isChecked() && cheese.isChecked()){
        str.append("Pepperoni, extra cheese pizza!");
    }

    else if (pepp.isChecked()){
        str.append("Pepperoni pizza!");
    }

    else if (cheese.isChecked()){
        str.append("Extra cheese pizza!");
    }

    tv.setText(str);
}

public void onlol(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Troll.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

Troll.java:

```
package com.example.pizza2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Troll extends Activity{

CheckBox box11, box22;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.troll);
    box11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    box22 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

}

public void onChecked1(View view){

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    if(box11.isChecked()){
    str.append("Lol bro!");
    }

    tv.setText(str);
}//end of "onChecked1"  


    public void onChecked2(View view){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        if(box22.isChecked()){
            str.append("XD XD Kaki");
        }
        tv.setText(str);

    } //end of "onChecked2" 
 }
```

Comment: Post your logcat here! and you can debug your code with breakpoints!so many reasons may cause your program crash

Comment: by the way, this was not copied from a book, it's all me, do you think I am talented or I am on the right way? I am only 15! Any tips or suggestions about the methods I use that are betten than mine.??

Comment: So you have the same textview(R.id.display) on 2 layouts `activity_main` and `troll` or are you making mistake of referencing to those textview?

Comment: my logcat is empty! How do i fix it please?

Comment: check you textview reference. it is same in both classes but different layout.it can b reason.

Comment: I tried but it does not work, maybe you can edit the source code i gave you??? please !!

Comment: do you think i am talented?? i am only 15!